# How to set the `type` property of the serialized JSON object in Ember

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

I have a model named `line-item` in my ember application. When I try to create a `line-item` record, I observe in the network tab that ember serialises a JSON object that looks like so:

```
{
    data: {
        quantity: 1,
        type: "lineItems", // note this
        links: {
            cart: {linkage: {id: "7", type: "carts"}}
            product: {linkage: {id: "a65874aa87b", type: "products"}}
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is change the value of the `type` property to `line-items` instead (since the backend expects that). I have tried overriding the `serializeIntoHash` and `typeForRoot` methods of the RESTSerializer class, but no luck there. I'm probably mucking around with the wrong methods, but I'm just not sure where I should be looking at instead.

I would really appreciate some pointers in the right direction.Thanks!

Comment: this looks like JSON api, are you using something like https://github.com/kurko/ember-json-api or are you rolling your own?

Comment: Indeed, I'm using (https://github.com/kurko/ember-json-api). The JSON i described above is the default behaviour I'm getting, but would like to override.